# Parse remote JSON with ruby

Tags: ruby, json

i have a problem when try to get and parse a remote JSON.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = "Www.example.com"
resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
buffer = resp.body
result = JSON.parse(buffer)

details = result['Detail']

details.each do |detail|
  puts "Latitude: #{detail['Latitude']}"
end
```

The JSON returned it's like this.

```
{Detail:{ID:578155,Latitude:69.83}}
```

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Well, this isn't a valid JSON and if parser doesn't want to parse it, it's absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a valid JSON, so i use split and gsub methods to parse it.

```
string = string.split("}")
string = string[0].gsub("[", "")
string = string[0].gsub("]", "")
string = string.split(",")
```